# At what dates did the Monero blockchain version update?

Tags: blockchain

I want to download the v1 and v2 versions of the Monero blockchain for experimental purposes, but since I don't know when the blockchain upgraded from v1 -> v2 and v2 -> v3, I don't know which node version to run.

Also if you know the blockheight, that would be beneficial as well!

Answer (score 3):

You can find the fork heights and approximate dates in [blockchain.cpp](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/961bb1bd2899ca168dd445eacef93ba7208b45a7/src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp#L89):

```
mainnet_hard_forks[] = {
  // version 1 from the start of the blockchain
  { 1, 1, 0, 1341378000 },

  // version 2 starts from block 1009827, which is on or around the 20th of March, 2016. Fork time finalised on 2015-09-20. No fork voting occurs for the v2 fork.
  { 2, 1009827, 0, 1442763710 },

  // version 3 starts from block 1141317, which is on or around the 24th of September, 2016. Fork time finalised on 2016-03-21.
  { 3, 1141317, 0, 1458558528 },

  // version 4 starts from block 1220516, which is on or around the 5th of January, 2017. Fork time finalised on 2016-09-18.
  { 4, 1220516, 0, 1483574400 },

  // version 5 starts from block 1288616, which is on or around the 15th of April, 2017. Fork time finalised on 2017-03-14.
  { 5, 1288616, 0, 1489520158 },  

  // version 6 starts from block 1400000, which is on or around the 16th of September, 2017. Fork time finalised on 2017-08-18.
  { 6, 1400000, 0, 1503046577 },

  // version 7 starts from block 1546000, which is on or around the 6th of April, 2018. Fork time finalised on 2018-03-17.
  { 7, 1546000, 0, 1521303150 },

  // version 8 starts from block 1685555, which is on or around the 18th of October, 2018. Fork time finalised on 2018-09-02.
  { 8, 1685555, 0, 1535889547 },

  // version 9 starts from block 1686275, which is on or around the 19th of October, 2018. Fork time finalised on 2018-09-02.
  { 9, 1686275, 0, 1535889548 },
};
```

Comment: That's when the hardforks happened, but the blockchain format stayed the same. Is there a way I can tell which version changed the block format?

Comment: Block format/version hasn't [changed](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blame/961bb1bd2899ca168dd445eacef93ba7208b45a7/src/cryptonote_config.h#L46). Are you asking about the database migrations?

Comment: Yes! What are database migrations and at what upgrades did they happen?

Comment: The migrations can be seen as and when implemented [here](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blame/961bb1bd2899ca168dd445eacef93ba7208b45a7/src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.h#L372). They are unlikely of interest though as they just update the schema of how stuff is stored internally. This doesn't affect things like blockchain / block / tx format.

Comment: @Dr-Bracket The earliest possible node version you could run, as a historical curiosity from before the bitmonero→monero fork, seems to be at [https://github.com/bitmonero-project/bitmonero](https://github.com/bitmonero-project/bitmonero).